# Openshift cron not working

Tags: cron, openshift-online-2

I'm using OpenShift and I have a shell script that is executable and can be run from the command line, however cron doesn't seem to even attempt to run it.

I have placed my shell script in ~/cron/minutely

When I run: /sbin/service crond status, I get "crond is stopped"
When I run: /sbin/service crond start, I get "User has insufficient privilege"
I am logged in as root.

I'm stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you add the cron cartridge to your application?

Comment: Yes I did, but somehow it appears to be turned off.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! As it turns out, there are multiple "cron" directories - and my shell script was in the wrong location. If a file isn't in the right place, the service won't run. This is the location that worked for me:

~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/

This post helped: https://forums.openshift.com/daily-cron-jobs-not-getting-triggered-automatically